# django @login_required decorator for a superuser

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a decorator in django similar to @login_required that also tests if the user is a superuser?

Thanks

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: How can I do that in CBVs?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: To make sure the user is an active user, you can use `@staff_member_required` in addition to `@user_passes_test`.

Answer (score 100):

In case **staff membership** is sufficient and you do **not** need to check whether the user is a superuser, you can use the `@staff_member_required` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: When I came here this is what I was looking for, that's why I put it here, and I will leave it here because I think it can be useful to someone else.

Comment: It is @Bit68. I am looking for it :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have similar functionality to @staff_member_required you can easily write your own decorator. Taking @staff_member as an example we can do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import user_passes_test

def superuser_required(view_func=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
                   login_url='account_login_url'):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in and is a
    superuser, redirecting to the login page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_superuser,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if view_func:
        return actual_decorator(view_func)
    return actual_decorator
```

This example is a modified staff_member_required, just changed one check in lambda.

Comment: You'll also want this import statement :)

`from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME`

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using Mixins, example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin


class SuperUserCheck(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

Then you can add `SuperUserCheck` to `View` class:

```
class MyView(SuperUserCheck, View):
```

Answer (score 4):

For class based views, creating a reusable decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import View


def superuser_required():
    def wrapper(wrapped):
        class WrappedClass(UserPassesTestMixin, wrapped):
            def test_func(self):
                return self.request.user.is_superuser

        return WrappedClass
    return wrapper

@superuser_required()
class MyClassBasedView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have your profile of user you can simply do this

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: True if u.profile.role==2 else False )
def add_listing(request):
    #...
```

Answer (score 2):

To require a superuser on a class based view without writing new code:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser), name='dispatch')
class AdminCreateUserView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if user is logged in use @login_required decorator and check if logged in user is superuser or not inside the function through if/else condition and return your response accordingly.

'''

```
    from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


    @login_required
    def function_name(request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Superuser')
```

'''