# creating admin restricted urls

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

so in my urls.py (outside django  default admin section ) i want to restrict some urls only to admin so if i have this for logged users

```
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^a1$',login_required( views.admin_area1 ), name='a1'),
        url(r'^a2$', login_required(views.admin_area2) , name='a2'),
        url(r'^a3', login_required(views.admin_area3) , name='a3'),
    ]
```

is there enyway torestrict these links to logged admins not just any logged user ? 
there is  but [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003808/590589) i can use `user_passes_test` but i have to use it in view

Comment: user_passes_test is the best way. BTW, don't mind me saying, if you want to be a good coder, develop a practice of reading docs instead of SO.

Comment: @SwakeertJain the problem with `user_passes_test ` is that i have to use it in the views which i  don't like  ,  thanks for the advice i do read docs but sometimes you want to get result fast and docs are huge withouth good examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the decorator returned by `user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)` in the same way that you use `login_required`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^a1$', user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)(views.admin_area1), name='a1'),
]
```

If you want to restrict access to admins, then it might be more accurate to use the [`staff_member_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#the-staff-member-required-decorator) decorator (which checks the [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) flag) instead of checking the [`is_superuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser) flag.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^a1$', staff_member_required(views.admin_area1), name='a1'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: thanx , i dont want to use django admin and i'm writing my own admin so i guess `staff_member_required` is what i want