# Do I make the is_superuser accessble to my api in django?

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I'm working on a project using django and angular and I need to make some pages accessible only to superusers. I've read somewhere that it isn't advisable to make this available to clients. If so is there any way to make some pages visible only to superusers? I'm new at this so forgive me if the question sound naive. Thank you

Comment: Of course there is; you can check permissions in the view. Are you using DRF?

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12003808/6485881) is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Yes @DanielRoseman I am.

Comment: It could be but I don't think i understand it. Like I said before I'm pretty new and I might need a little explanation to go with the answer

Comment: Well there's a whole [page on permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) in the DRF documentation.

Comment: I see that but what I'm looking for is actually frontend related. I want to use the is_superuser attribute to know if a logged in user can visit the 'achives' page for example, if not they should be redirected with the message that they don't have access to visit the page @DanielRoseman